# C naming conventions: hidden variables / macros

Tags: c, naming-conventions

IIRC, one shall not use built in names (e.g. `open`, `read`, etc.), names that start with underscore and capital letters (e.g. `_Thread`), names that start with double underscore or contain it (e.g. `__GCC__`). Even more for POSIX compatibility (see GCC naming conventions).

I'm creating a new library, where each function, type or macro begins with prefix (written in capital letters if it is a macro). However, I doubt which names I must use if I create a variable which is global but hidden. Or if it is a macro. Anyway, it shall be hidden. Is there any naming convention that I shall use? I thought that I may use `__mycustomprefix_global`, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

*UPDATE*
I know about `static` and use it everywhere where it is possible. However, I'm speaking about the case where variables/functions/macros must certainly be global.

Comment: If a variable is not needed outside a translation unit, declare it as `static` and do not worry about naming, as it wouldn't be visible even to the linker.

Comment: @DevSolar I should have written about it. Yes, I know about it and use it everywhere where it is possible. However, I'm speaking about the case where variables/functions/macros must certainly be global. :-(

Comment: Prefixing is good. BTW: dont forget names starting with `mem` or `str`, these are also reserved for the library.

Comment: @wildplasser That's the reason why I mentioned GCC naming conventions.

Comment: No, not just GCC, but the language / library definition and standardisation.

Comment: @ghostmansd: I implemented a C standard library once, and used _MYPREFIX_* for everything "private" (i.e., beyond the standard functions I implemented) that was visible to either compiler or linker. Yes, that is "reserved" by the letter of the standard, but better to use something that might collide with the compiler (i.e. in your testbed), than using something that might collide with **some** client's code *somewhere* (beyond your ability to test for it).

Comment: See here: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: @DevSolar Well, I've been working on FreeBSD's libc, implementing collation, and they prefer to use double leading underscore. The names are ctyptic and long enough sometimes. :-)

Comment: @ghostmansd: That's exactly why I *didn't* use double underscore for my prefix: Most compiler internals are double-underscore. Also keeps the prefix short.

Comment: @wildplasser: Ah... the future library directions. OK, got me there, original outburst deleted, lesson learned. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, identifiers starting with leading underscores are reserved for new language keywords, the C runtime and standard library as well as compiler intrinsics, so you should not use them.

However, if you use a namespace prefix, the chance of collisions are probably low so it won't matter in pratice. Personally, I'd go with a trailing underscore.